# How to trigger a SignalR command outside of the front end

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr, signalr-service

I feel like I'm either missing the point of the SignalR service or I've got the architecture of it wrong.

Using an Azure SignalR service I've got the front-end to front-end communication working as such;

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    app.MapAzureSignalR(this.GetType().FullName);
}
```

**Hub.cs**

```
private void BroadcastMessage(string message)
{
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
}
```

**Index.html**

```
hubName.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {
    alert(message);
};

$('#btn').click(function () {
    hubName.server.broadcastMessage("Hello World");
});
```

This is fine, and when I need the back-end to trigger a message I am using the following;

**Functions.cs**

```
HubConnection signalr = new HubConnection("http://localhost:57690/");
IHubProxy hub = null;
if (signalr.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
{
    hub = signalr.CreateHubProxy(hubName);
    signalr.Start().Wait();
}
hub.Invoke(functionName, args);
signalr.Stop();
```

While this works it leaves me wondering if I have implemented it wrong as this leaves `http://localhost:57690/signalr/hubs` open to posts from any source.

In the front-end, I have to provide the `Endpoint=https://appName.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=xxxxx` setting but not from the back-end.

As well as a security concern, this leaves me questioning what purpose the SignalR service has in this.

Surely there must be a better way to invoke signalr from the back-end.

Many Thanks,

Tom

Comment: "but not from the back-end", isn't that everyone wants? It is the same backend application (same OS process), so why do you want access key? I don't see a security concern here.

Answer (score 0):

In the Startup.cs you gotta have a line of code like this

```
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();
```

By not passing a parameter to `AddAzureSignalR()`, this code uses the default configuration key, `Azure:SignalR:ConnectionString`, for the SignalR Service resource connection string.

You can find more info in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core)

Comment: I should have been more specific sorry - this is asp.Net 4.7.1 not Core.


I think the syntax for Core is `.AddAzureSignalR()` where as the syntax for .net is `.MapAzureSignalR()`.

I have my endpoint connection string in the webconfig with the name of `Azure:SignalR:ConnectionString` already which gives me the security on front-end to front-end.

Comment: Actually, your hub is between frontend - frontend. it basically means, your both frontend connects to your hub via the connection string.